# Android Studio Chipmunk - hiding properties in debugger view

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, ide

Having an issue with my debugger after I have installed a new Android Studio version..

Maybe someone knows how to remove these duplicated values from a debugger?

Kind regards

[image]

Comment: Can you expand your question a little more? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: As you can see there are duplicated values with get() method. How can I hide them?